# What do I have to consider for the functional and technical specification of a user registration process?

Tags: registration

What user experience aspects do I have to consider for the technical specification of a user registration process?

Answer (score 2):

Before figuring out user experience, one has to

- define username and password length and signs: usernames should be limited to something readable (e.g. 25 sign) and not contain whitespace as this makes them harder to read in plain text. Password should be sufficiently complex and have a minimal length and a large maximal length[1]
- whether it's necessary to define and email for the registration (most probably) and whether this email needs to be validation and when (before leaving the registration site or within x hours)

Then it's possible to apply the following rules:

- avoid trial error registration (e.g. user enters a too short username, you tell that the username is too short only, then the user enters a username with a disallowed digit, you tell only that, then the user enters the password 123, then he enters his email address and you tell that he's already registered and can recover his password) -> give all information about all constraints as early as possible
- sort the registration data by relevance, i.e. check whether a username has already been used before whether an email address has already been used before validating username, password and other constraints
- check captcha validity in parallel, i.e. together with other validation and don't enforce passing a captcha twice because either you trust it or not

---

[1] reading entry point https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32222/are-password-complexity-rules-counterproductive with link to https://xkcd.com/936/